# Return false statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR; I want create the following statement. I've an array; I want that controller return false if all array elements are not equal to a variable value.This is the code

```
def check_warehouse(asset,serial)
  wh = Warehouse.where(["(asset = ? and serial = ?) OR (asset = ?) OR (serial= ?)",asset,serial,asset,serial])
  return false if wh.count > 1
  return false if
  wh.each do |wh|
    wh.position_id != session[:position_id]
  end
end
```

but it doesn't works!why?

Moreover, can you suggest me a plugin or gem running on Rails 3.1 for generate pdf from RoR datas?
Thank you all

Comment: It's not helpful to say "it doesn't work". Be descriptive about what doesn't work -- provide error messages, describe what you expected to happen, etc.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about your error ? Also for pdf export, check out `whhtmltopdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
def check_warehouse(asset,serial)
  wh = Warehouse.where(["(asset = ?) OR (serial= ?)",asset,serial]) # first condition was just extra
  return false if wh.detect {|wh| wh.position_id != session[:position_id] }
end
```

I removed `return false if wh.count > 1` because there's no sense to check the array if you return if it has more than 1 element. Please tell me if I misunderstood you

UPD

Actually you can do that in the db:

```
def check_warehouse(asset,serial)
  Warehouse.where(
    ["(asset = ? OR serial= ?) AND NOT position_id = ?", asset, serial, session[:position_id]]
  ).count.zero?
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You have this code:

```
return false if wh.each do |wh|
  wh.position_id != session[:position_id]                    
end
```

This will not execute the way you want. In ruby, .each will execute the "block" (code between do/end) and return to you the original array.

So if wh is an array, empty or not, and you say:

```
return false if []
```

ruby will not return false. instead, you'd likely rather:

```
return false if wh.any? {|wh| wh.position_id != session[:position_id] }
```

You probably would want it to return true if the position is the session position, so you can switch to:

```
return wh.any?{|wh| wh.position_id == session[:position_id] }
```